# java myClass -p Parameter1 Parameter2 Parameter3 Parameter4

Tags: java

java myClass -p Parameter1 Parameter2 Parameter3 Parameter4 
What is the effect of this -p option here ?
when we should use it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The meaning of `-p` is whatever meaning your application assigns to it.

It is usually used to pass multiple optional parameters in arbitrary order.

For example

```
java myClass -p Parameter1 -r Parameter2
```

lets your app know that Parameter1 is of type "p" (whatever that means in your app) and Parameter2 is of type "r".

Without specifying those types :

```
java myClass Parameter1 Parameter2
```

your app can decide the purpose of Parameter1 and Parameter2 only based on their position and you can't pass them in a different order (`java myClass Parameter1 Parameter2`) or pass only the second parameter (`java myClass Parameter2`).

With the types you have this flexibility :

```
java myClass -p Parameter1 -r Parameter2
java myClass -r Parameter2 -p Parameter1
java myClass -r Parameter2
```

Answer (score 3):

The short answer is that it doesn't have any effect.

There is nothing special about a "-p" parameter. It's just another parameter that's passed into your Java application. You can access it via the array passed into the main method.

Why don't you test this out yourself by running a program like this:

```
public class Main{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        for(String parameter : args){
            System.out.println(parameter);
        }
    }
}
```

Run that program with your arguments, and you'll see it print out:

-p
Parameter1
Parameter2
Parameter3
Parameter4

So the significance of that -p parameter is really up to the programmer, just like the significance of any command-line argument is up to the programmer.